# LWJGL and Slick textures display as black...?

Tags: java, binding, textures, lwjgl

I use eclipse. so in my workspace, under my project, i create a new folder "res" with a subfolder "images" that have all my png's for use as textures. so here is the method im using for loading the textures:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import java.util.Random;

public class TextureDemo
{
public int count = 0;
private static Texture wood;
Random random = new Random();
public TextureDemo()
{
    initGL(640, 480, "SLICK TEXTURES");
    loadTexture("mozilla");

    int x = 100, y = 100, count = 0, width = 0, height = 0, counter = 10;

    while(true)
    {
        count++;
        if(count == counter)
        {
            x--; y--; width++; height++; counter += random.nextInt(50) + 1;
        }
        render(x, y, width, height);

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);

        if(Display.isCloseRequested())
        {

            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}


private void initGL(int width, int height, String title)
{
    try
    {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));

        Display.setTitle(title);
        Display.create();
    }
    catch(LWJGLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(1);
    }



    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

}
public void loadTexture(String key)
{
    try
    {

        wood = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("./res/images/"+key+".png"));

        System.out.println("working." + wood.getTextureID());
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
public void render(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    System.out.println("working." + wood.getTextureID());

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, wood.getTextureID());
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);


    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x + wood.getImageWidth(), y);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x + wood.getImageWidth(), y + wood.getImageHeight());
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x, y + wood.getImageHeight());

    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);

    System.out.println(wood.getHeight()+ " " +wood.getWidth());


}
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    new TextureDemo();


}
```

}

WHY WHY WHY are my textures black lol? I really don't understand how my code did this. Is it possible that my computer could have problems that are causing that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, however there are many problems with your code. I would recommend taking a look at some opengl tutorials. The arcsynthesis one is very in-depth.

Your problem is that the texture "wood" is never bound to opengl.

In order to bind your texture to the opengl context you must call

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
```

before glbegin()

The id is the texture id generated by `glGentextures` or in your case the slick util method.
Also what is wood? In the first code block it is the texture id but in the second block you are calling 'getHeght()' on type wood. I am confused as to what 'wood' is.

Either way, you need to bind the texture for opengl to use it and I again recommending looking at a few tutorials on the opengl basics.

Comment: *"however, there are many problems with your code"*: Would you mind pointing out all of the problems?

Comment: I apologize. They are more so poor practice than bad code. I am assuming that the getHeight/width methods are referring to the texture so setting the coords to the textures size seems odd. Passing in the vertex positions through the same method that would bind the texture and use the gl calls is just messy and quads aren't used very often. he also should unbind the texture after the rendering.

Comment: I have it bound to the open gl. It is displaying as a black quad. I have tried several different images, at different sizes, all powers of 2. wood is a texture name. ill update the render method

Comment: My fault - I forgot to add that you need to call glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) as well. Do this in one of your initialization methods.

Comment: I also have that in my initgl method... would u like to see the entire class?

Comment: note: the parameters width and height are not in use in render

Comment: From the source code you gave me I added glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and it worked just fine.  http://i.imgur.com/JCjOUhT.png

Comment: idk... maybe its a problem with how im loading the textures? How should I put the pics in the res folder, inside the project folder? The screen is simply coming gray...

Comment: Try setting the "PNG" in TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", //stuff); to lowercase. And I loaded my image file called "checker" fine. Maybe make sure your file isn't called "texture.png" because when you load it that would have the textureLoader load "texture.png.png" which wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Asking the same question twice won't help. However, you should make sure you first call `glBindTexture`, before you start `glBegin`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't enabled textures!
In your initGL method call GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D).